# Angular Api get request issue

Tags: angularjs, typescript

So i want to use angular to get a certain value from this api:

https://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json

i am using at the moment

```
app.controller("api", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.home = "This is the homepage";

    $scope.getRequest = function() {
      console.log("I've been pressed!");
      $http.get("https://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json").then(
        function successCallback(response) {
          //$scope.response = response.data;
          console.log("response.data.MRData.StandingsTable");
          console.log(response.data.MRData.StandingsTable);
          console.log("response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists.0.DriverStandings");
          console.log(response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists.DriverStandings);

        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log("Unable to perform get request");
        }
      );
    };
  });
```

which gives me this as return

[image: the return i get with the current code]

the 0 in the way i dont know how to pass that value it wont let me put it in the request  and i want to get to DriverStandings array in that api.

Answer (score 0):

ah the answer is simple :( this is it:

console.log(response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0]);

since it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just use: response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings
the [0] since the StandingsLists is an Array.